# Join Tables in Single List

Tags: php, odbc

I have two tables, `Calls` & `Vehicles`.  `Calls` has the call number and address.  `Vehicles` has the call number and vehicle number.  (Multiple vehicles can be on a call).  I want to show a list of all calls and show which unit(s) are on which calls.

Something like:

```
Call    Address      Vehicles
1       123 Main St  A1, B3, C2
2       124 Main St  C3
3       125 Main St  A2, A3
```

Code:

```
$query = 'select calls.call, calls.address, vehicles.vehicle from calls left join vehicles on calls.call = vehicles.call';
$select = odbc_exec($conn, $query);
$while ($data = odbc_fetch_array($select)){

echo"<table>";
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>".$data['call']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$data['address']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$data['vehicle']."</td>";
echo"</tr>";
echo"</table>";
}
```

When I do this I get multiple calls with multiple vehicles listed multiple times.  How can I get just one of each call with the vehicles in a comma separated list?

Comment: What database are you using? In MySQL this is `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Why are you joining with `vehicles`? You're not using anything from that table.

Comment: Database is ctreeACE SQL.  I have tried GROUP_CONCAT, but it doesn't seem to work with ctreeACE SQL.

Comment: Mistyped the query.  It should be vehicles.vehicle.  I've edited the original post.

Comment: It looks like c-treeACE doesn't have this operation built in. You can easily group them together in the PHP, by making an associative array that uses `$data['call']` as the key and putting all the vehicles in an array.

Comment: Then you can use `implode(', ', $results['vehicles'])` to get the comma-separated list you want in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctreeACE doesn't have a `GROUP_CONCAT` function, so do it in PHP. First create an associative array whose keys are the call numbers.

```
$results = array();
$query = 'select calls.call, calls.address, vehicles.vehicle from calls left join vehicles on calls.call = vehicles.call';
$select = odbc_exec($conn, $query);
while ($data = odbc_fetch_array($select)){
    $c = $data['call'];
    if (!isset($results[$c])) {
        $results[$c] = array('call' => $c, 'address' => $data['address'], 'vehicles' => array());
    }
    if ($data['vehicle']) { // Don't append NULL vehicle that LEFT JOIN might produce if there's no matching row
        $results[$c]['vehicles'][] = $data['vehicle'];
    }
}
```

Then loop through that to produce the table.

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ($results as $call) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$call['call']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$call['address']}</td>";
    echo "<td>" . implode(', ', $call['vehicles']) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Also notice that you shouldn't start a new table inside the loop, it should be around the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I've copied the code directly and the page fails to display.  Not sure if I'm missing something else.

Comment: The `$` before `while` was a typo.

Comment: Thanks, I believe there is also a missing `)` on line 6 above and the `= array());` needs to be removed from the end of line 7.

Comment: Actually, the mistake is that `= array()` should be `=> array()`.

Comment: The calls and address shows now, but I get no vehicles, the server log shows `PHP Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed`

Comment: Sorry, left out the `[]` when adding to `$results[$c]['vehicles']` in the first loop.

Comment: Awesome, now the only issue is row 1 only shows call 1; row 2 shows call 1 and call 2; row 3 shows call 1, call 2 and call 3; etc...

Comment: I don't see how that could be happening. Could you post your full code on pastebin.com?

Comment: I ran the code at phpfiddle.org and didn't get extra results on each row.

Comment: I had the `}` for the while loop in the wrong place.  Thanks for all your help!